# How to make Immutables library skip serializing Optional fields

Tags: java, json, jackson, immutables-library

I am working with Immutables library (https://immutables.github.io). I need my classes to serialize to JSON (I use Jackson). I want to skip Optional fields in my output JSON. Before Immutables, I provided `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` at class level.

It seems, Immutables is not respecting that annotation.
If I annotate every Optional field with `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)` it works fine.

Is it possible to instruct Immutables to skip serializing empty Optionals using class-level (not field-level) annotation? I see `org.immutables.value.Value.Style#additionalJsonAnnotations` but there is no customize passed annotation using it.

I have jackson-datatype-jdk8 in my classpath, and my `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` has

> mapper.registerModule(new
>   Jdk8Module().configureAbsentsAsNulls(true));

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jdk8 ?

Comment: yes. It works if I configure @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) at field-level but Immutables library is not respecting this annotation at class-level.

Comment: I can't replicate your problem locally. Annotating my immutable class with `@JsonInclude` makes Jackson omit the empty, optional field. Which version of Immutables are you using?

Comment: @Henrik issue is indeed resolved in latest immutables. I posted answer to my question, clarifying that. Thanks for bumping the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is resolved in Immutables since version v2.3.6 (possibly earlier).
Immutables is respecting `@JsonInclude`, `@JsonPropertyOrder` and other class-level (or field-level) annotations from Jackson. Those annotations are copied to generated Immutable class and they work as expected.